# Arabic is not typing as "right to left" when it's editing in WPBakery

Tags: wordpress, wpml, wpbakery

When I am trying to edit and type text in WPBakery editor it's typing in the wrong direction. Arabic should be typed from right to left but it's typing from left to right. it's weird because everything is working fine except this issue.[image]

Comment: Give your text blocks a universal class and then put this in your css file `className { direction: rtl; }`

Comment: universal class is also will affect to english editor ?

Comment: I assumed the whole website would be in Arabic; yes, it would make all text run from right to left.

Comment: I just need to make right to left for just Arabic content. is there any solution for this ?